# reading bits from a binary file in C language

Tags: c, file, binary, bit

[image: i have a binary file with data as in the picture]

every 3 bits represent a row or a col. i need to read every 3 bits and store them in a variable.

this is my code so far:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE

void main()
{

    FILE* fh = fopen("knightPath.bin", "rb");
    checkFileOpening(fh);

    BYTE ch ,ch1, ch2;

    fread(&ch, sizeof(BYTE), 1, fh);
    ch1 = ch >> 5; /* first 3 bits 'C' */
    ch2 = ch << 3 >> 5; /* second 3 bits '5' */

    fclose(fh);
}
```

The problem is reading the bits from the letter A because i have 2 bits of it in the variable ch and the next bit will be in the next BYTE i read from the file.

i thought about using mask but i am not sure how.

any ideas? how can i work this out?

thanks

Comment: Always check if `FILE*` returned by `fopen()` is `NULL`. If it's `NULL`, you should throw some error. Also, check the return value of `fread()`.

Comment: By writing a function which has a byte buffer (as `unsigned int`) and a bit count. If there are enough bits in the buffer, extract them and update the variables. If not, read another byte from file and merge it with the buffer. If it's at the end, `return -1` (for example).

Comment: I do so in my function checkFileOpening(fh);

Comment: Please post the full code for better analysis.

Comment: @WeatherVane   Do you have a code example?

Comment: I don't get how the hex values shown relate to each bit triplet in the graphic. It's also not stated whether the first bit in the file is bit 0 or bit 7 of the first byte.

Comment: @WeatherVane: In each 6 bits, the first 3 encode a letter A-H and the second 3 encode a number 1-8. The code `ch1 = ch >> 5;` reveals the high 3 bits are the first three bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FILENAME "knightPath.bin"

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int c, ch1, ch2;
    int remain = 0;                     // remaining buffer (FIFO) size in bit
    int buf = 0;                        // FIFO of bit stream

    if (NULL == (fp = fopen(FILENAME, "rb"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", FILENAME);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1) {
        if (remain < 6) {               // if the FIFO size < 6
            c = fgetc(fp);              // then read next byte
            if (c == EOF) return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            remain += 8;                // increase the buffer size
            buf = (buf << 8) + c;       // append the byte to the FIFO
        }
        ch1 = (buf >> (remain - 3)) & 7;// get the leftmost 3 bits
        ch2 = (buf >> (remain - 6)) & 7;// get the next 3 bits
        printf("ch1 = %c, ch2 = %d\n", ch1 + 'A', ch2 + 1);
        remain -= 6;                    // decrease the FIFO size
        buf &= ((1 << remain) - 1);     // clear the processed bits
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ch1 = C, ch2 = 5
ch1 = A, ch2 = 4
ch1 = B, ch2 = 3
ch1 = D, ch2 = 1
ch1 = E, ch2 = 3
```

Answer (score -1):

To read binary data from an binary file we need to use this line of codes.
`unsigned char buffer[10];
FILE *ptr;

ptr = fopen("test.bin","rb");  // r for read, b for binary

fread(buffer,sizeof(buffer),1,ptr); // read 10 bytes to our buffer`

Comment: OP knows this: but wants to know how to extract and align the bit fields which might span more than one byte.